# AChartEngine display value alignment

Tags: android, achartengine

Using AChartEngine, I'd like to be able to specify a kind of Align.AUTO for XYSeriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign() that would make it align differently according to position (practically, .LEFT for the minX point, .RIGHT for the maxX point, .CENTER for the rest). This would make all values easily legible. Is there any chance to achieve such a display without modifying the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, OOP to the rescue. :-)

```
public class LineChartAligned extends LineChart {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public LineChartAligned(XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    super(dataset, renderer);
  }

  @Override
  protected void drawChartValuesText(Canvas canvas, XYSeries series, SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer, Paint paint, List<Float> points, int seriesIndex, int startIndex) {
    if (points.size() > 1) {
      float previousPointX = points.get(0);
      float previousPointY = points.get(1);
      for (int k = 0; k < points.size(); k += 2) {
        if (k == 2) {
          if (Math.abs(points.get(2) - points.get(0)) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance() || Math.abs(points.get(3) - points.get(1)) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance()) {
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT); // <<<
            drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), series.getY(startIndex)), points.get(0), points.get(1) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
            paint.setTextAlign(renderer.getChartValuesTextAlign()); // <<<
            drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), series.getY(startIndex + 1)), points.get(2), points.get(3) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
            previousPointX = points.get(2);
            previousPointY = points.get(3);
          }
        }
        else if (k > 2) {
          if (Math.abs(points.get(k) - previousPointX) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance() || Math.abs(points.get(k + 1) - previousPointY) > renderer.getDisplayChartValuesDistance()) {
            paint.setTextAlign((k >= points.size() - 2) ? Align.RIGHT : renderer.getChartValuesTextAlign()); // <<<
            drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), series.getY(startIndex + k / 2)), points.get(k), points.get(k + 1) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
            previousPointX = points.get(k);
            previousPointY = points.get(k + 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else
      for (int k = 0; k < points.size(); k += 2)
        drawText(canvas, getLabel(renderer.getChartValuesFormat(), series.getY(startIndex + k / 2)), points.get(k), points.get(k + 1) - renderer.getChartValuesSpacing(), paint, 0);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't this exact behavior, but you could use annotations for this. You can place them wherever you want in the graph:

```
series.addAnnotation(text, x, y);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but... It won't appear nicely above the chart at a set distance and it won't align unless I start to calculate string width (taking into account zoom and everything). Besides, if I'm not mistaken, it uses the chart title color and text size which is not really an advantage...